# How to order an array of objects and set the first element

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to order an array of objects where I specify the first element, example below.

**Raw data in javascript**

```
{title: 'test 1', text: 'aa'},
{title: 'test 2', text: 'bb'},
{title: 'display first', text: 'this is an example'},
{title: 'test 4', text: 'dd'}
```

**After the reorder**

```
var elementToDisplayFirst = "display first";

{title: 'display first', text: 'this is an example'},
{title: 'test 1', text: 'aa'},
{title: 'test 2', text: 'bb'},
{title: 'test 4', text: 'dd'}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You must have a universal criterion for ordering. Is this the alphabetical order of title property? Or something else?

Comment: the remaining items can be ordered by title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom sort function

```js
var arr = [{
    title: 'Fuchsia',
    text: 'paniculata'
  },
  {
    title: 'Panthera',
    text: 'leo'
  },
  {
    title: 'Canis',
    text: 'lupus'
  },
  {
    title: 'display first',
    text: 'Forrest Gump'
  },
  {
    title: 'Felis',
    text: 'silvestris'
  }
]

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.title === 'display first') {
    return -1
  } else if (b.title === 'display first') {
    return 1
  } else return  a.title < b.title ? -1 : a.title > b.title ? 1 : 0;
})

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if `title` is the wanted string and take the inverted (b - a) delta, because the check returns a boolean and you want a descending order of `true` (1) and `false` (0).

```js
var array = [{ title: 'test 1', text: 'aa' }, { title: 'test 2', text: 'bb' }, { title: 'display first', text: 'this is an example' }, { title: 'test 4', text: 'dd' }]
    first = "display first";
    
array.sort(({ title: a }, { title: b }) => 
    (b === first) - (a === first) ||
    a > b || -(a < b)
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I would add to the sort function `({ title: a }, { title: b }) => (b === first) - (a === first) || a.localeCompare(b)`

Comment: the actual implementations of `sort` is stable, no need to sort by another criterium.

Comment: I meant: Instead of `array.sort(({ title: a }, { title: b }) => (b === first) - (a === first));` use this `array.sort(({ title: a }, { title: b }) => (b === first) - (a === first) || a.localeCompare(b));` to sort the other items, which should not come first by title

Comment: as i read the question, op wants to move *first* to top and keep the rest in order.

Comment: Look at the comment